# Find set intersection of multiple arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rows, intersection

I tried to solve this problem, but I could not implement.
Could you help me anything for this?

**Problem**

```
Mat1 | Mat2 | Mat3

 1 2 | 1 3  | 2 6

 1 3 | 2 6  | 2 5

 2 4 | 3 1  | 3 1

 3 1 | 3 5  | 5 2

 4 5 |
```

When there are 3 matrices(for example above), I want to get this result for the intersection rows in `[column1 column2 matrixnumber]` form.

The result for above example would be

```
1 3 1

1 3 2

2 6 2

2 6 3

3 1 1

3 1 2

3 1 3
```

It would be OK if the result is in the form `[column1 column2 firstmatrix secondmatrix, ...]`

```
1 3 1 2

2 6 2 3

3 1 1 2 3
```

For this problem, I want to use at most one for-loop.

Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Just to be sure: what do you want to see if a pair occurs on all three matrices? All three pairwise occurances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here an alternative solution (which seems to run faster than Gunther's) using MATLAB's [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html):

```
Mat = {[1 2; 1 3; 2 4; 3 1; 4 5],
       [1 3; 2 6; 3 1; 3 5],
       [2 6; 2 5; 3 1; 5 2]};

result = zeros(sum(cellfun(@(x)size(x, 1), Mat)), 3); % # Preallocate memory
k = 1;
for cc = transpose(nchoosek(1:numel(Mat), 2))
    x = intersect(Mat{cc}, 'rows');                   % # Find intersection
    y = ones(size(x, 1), 2) * diag(cc);               % # Generate matrix indices
    result(k:k + numel(y) - 1, :) = [[x; x], y(:)];
    k = k + numel(y);
end

result(all(~result, 2), :) = [];                      % # Discard zero rows
result = unique(result, 'rows');                      % # Discard repeated rows
```

The matrix `result` should now contain the unique intersection rows and their corresponding matrix indices, just like you want:

```
result =   
     1     3     1
     1     3     2
     2     6     2
     2     6     3
     3     1     1
     3     1     2
     3     1     3
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you have a number of sets of pairs: `Mat1`,`Mat2`, `Mat3`, ... `MatN`. Now you want to find the unique pairs and then find out in which set every unique pair appears.

If you have a large number of sets, I suggest you start using a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) to hold them all, makes things a lot easier:

```
N = 3; % total number of data sets
Mat = cell(N,1);
Mat{1} = [1 2;
          1 3;
          2 4;
          3 1;
          4 5];
Mat{2} = [1 3;
          2 6;
          3 1;
          3 5];
Mat{3} = [2 6;
          2 5;
          3 1;
          5 2];
% etc.
```

First let's find the unique pairs:

```
uniq_pairs = unique(cat(1,Mat{:}),'rows');
M = size(uniq_pairs ,1);
```

Then use [ismember](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to check which sets contain which pairs:

```
matcontpair = false(M,N); %preallocate
for ii=1:N % unavoidable loop
    matcontpair(:,ii) = ismember(uniq_pairs,Mat{ii},'rows');
end
```

To translate this intersection matrix to a set of matrix numbers for each pair, loop through it again and store the final result in a cell array (you can't use an array, because they might not be of same size (some pairs only  found once, other twice, other three times ...)

```
pair_occurence= cell(M,1);
d=1:N;
for jj=1:M
    pair_occurence{jj} = d(matcontpair(jj,:));
end
```

Now you have a matrix `uniq_pairs` of size `Mx2` containing the unique pairs, and a occurence cell array `pair_occurence` of size `Mx1`: each cell corresponds to a pair and contains a list of matrices where the pair is present.

If you want to remove pairs from the list which are only present in one matrix, use the following:

```
% find them
lonely_pairs = cellfun(@numel,pair_occurence)<2;
% and destroy them
uniq_pairs(lonely_pairs,:) = [];
pair_occurence(lonely_pairs) = [];
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. When I check the solution, it may take some time for unique of rows and ismember function in for loop. 'unique' of rows takes long if the number of rows is huge. 'ismember' function in for loop means that it search all matrix for each row, so it may take some time(O(# of unique rows * # of all rows). Do you think that your solution is the optimized one?

Comment: you do want to find each row in each matrix isn't it? try out @EitanT's solution, that should be faster if there are a lot unique rows.