# find intersect of Multi arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

If I have several arrays:

```
A = [7 1 7 7 4]; 

B = [7 0 4 4 0];

C = [0 0 4 1 5]; 

D = [5 7 2 4 0];
```

I know in Matlab "intersect" can find the shared elements between two matrices with their indexes. If I want to use it for four matrices, how can I do it?

Note: This can be used for two matrices as:
[K,ia,ib] = intersect(A,B)

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080190/find-set-intersection-of-multiple-arrays-in-matlab

Comment: Thanks! I found this equation which is what I wanted. Your helps are really appreciated.
http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24835-intersect-several-arrays

Comment: You're welcome. I see that @Divakar has provided a very nice and efficient answer; you might want to check it out as well as accepting it if it helped you.

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi Would be interesting to see how the posted solution here performs against the FEX one!

Answer (score 2):

You could concatenate all input arrays (vectors) into a `2D` array and then try to find the unique elements that exist in all input arrays. The `bsxfun` based code presented next tries to achieve the same -

```
%// Concatenate all vector arrays into a 2D array 
M = cat(1,A,B,C,D)

%// Find unique values for all elements in all arrays
unqvals = unique(M(:),'stable')'  %//'

%// Find which unqiue elements are common across all arrays, which is the
%// desired output
out = unqvals(all(any(bsxfun(@eq,M,permute(unqvals,[1 3 2])),2),1))
```

Code Output -

```
M =
     7     1     7     7     4
     7     0     4     4     0
     0     0     4     1     5
     5     7     2     4     0
unqvals =
     7     1     4     0     5     2
out =
     4
```

To verify against an `intersect` based code, one form of whose would look like this -

```
out1 = intersect(intersect(intersect(A,B,'stable'),C,'stable'),D,'stable')
```

For the given inputs, it would give -

```
out1 =
     4
```

To  verify it further, let's say you introduce a `7` into `C` i.e. `C = [0 7 4 1 5]`, making `7` available in all input arrays, you would have the output as `[7 4]`.

---

If you would like to make `bsxfun` work with a `2D` array which could be more memory efficient, here's an alternative -

```
%// Concatenate all vector arrays into a 2D array 
M = cat(1,A,B,C,D)

%// Find unique values for all elements in all arrays
unqvals = unique(M(:),'stable')'    %//'

[m1,m2] = size(M) %// Get size of concatenated 2D array

%// Matches for all elements in all arrays against the unique elements
matches = bsxfun(@eq,reshape(M',[],1),unqvals)  %//'

%// Desired output
out = unqvals(all(any(permute(reshape(matches,m2,m1,[]),[1 3 2]),1),3))
```

Comment: Thanks! I found this equation which is what I wanted. Your helps are really appreciated.
http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24835-intersect-several-arrays

Comment: I definitely need to start using bsxfun more often. +1 from me!

Comment: @Benoit_11 You work with IP a lot, right? Trust me, `bsxfun` works wonders with it, specially with IP on MATLAB has loads of scope because in many cases you are working on pixels independently! Just give it more practice, that's all there is :)

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi See if this solution works? If it does consider accepting it?