# Finding equal rows between multiple arrays of different sizes by voting

Tags: arrays, matlab, compare

Let's say I have 5 arrays of different sizes. All of the arrays have the same number of columns, in my case 2, but a different number of rows. I need to find the elements of the rows that appear in at least 3 of such arrays.

Right now, I compare two arrays using `ismember`, then compare that result with the third array and then save the row values which occur in all the three arrays. I do this for every possible combination of 3 arrays; basically in my case, I have 10 of such operations in total. It's like choosing three out of 5 without repetitions.

It works, but I am looking for a more efficient implementation. In particular, I was looking for any implementation that can perform this by voting. It's like having sets of different sizes and trying to find the elements that appear in the majority of sets, in my case 3 arrays out of 5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find set intersection of multiple arrays in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080190/find-set-intersection-of-multiple-arrays-in-matlab)

Comment: `@ excaza`: Based on my understanding, the solution provided in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080190/find-set-intersection-of-multiple-arrays-in-matlab) works better for comparing each pair of arrays. For example, it saves all the arrays in one cell and then finds the intersection of each pair of arrays. Finally, finds the unique rows as well as the array in which they appear. In my problem it seems like putting all the arrays in one big matrix is more efficient. I think comparing each pair of arrays involves more comparisons, which doesn't seem to be efficient here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by voting but I think does what you are looking for.

It creates 1 big unique matrix of all the rows from the arrays.  The does an `ismember` by rows of the unique array with each individual array.  The `ismember` is summed together to get a count of how many times each unique row exists across your set of arrays.

You can then use that count to return a new array that has at least `minNum` occurrences.

You would call it like this:

```
>> [outRows, uRows, memCount]= getRowDuplicates(3,a,b,c,d,e)
```

Where a,b,c,d,e are you arrays and 3 is the minimum number of occurrences

```
function [outRows, uRows, memCount]= getRowDuplicates(minNum,varargin)

uRows = unique(vertcat(varargin{:}),'rows');
memCount = false(size(uRows,1),1);
for j = 1:nargin-1
    memCount = memCount + ismember(uRows,varargin{j},'rows');    
end
rowIdx = memCount >= minNum;
outRows = uRows(rowIdx,:);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Aero Engy** for the solution! This is my own attempt, after rewriting my initial, not very efficient, implementation. I thought someone might find it useful:

```
function [majorityPts] = MajorityPointSelection(Mat, numMajority)
    result = vertcat(Mat{:});
    allUniq = unique(result(:,1:2),'rows');
    numUniq = size(allUniq,1);

    allUniq = [allUniq zeros(numUniq,1); zeros(size(result,1)-numUniq, 3)];
    for i = 1:numUniq
        sumNumRow = sum(result(:,1:2) == allUniq(i,1:2),1);
        allUniq(i,3) = sumNumRow(1);
    end

    allUniq(numUniq+1:end,:) = [];
    majorityPts = allUniq(allUniq(:,3)>=numMajority,1:2);
end
```

Here `Mat` is a cell that contains all of the arrays that I want to compare in order to find the rows that appear in at least `numMajority` of them, where in my case `numMajority = 3`. Basically, I first dump all of the arrays in one big matrix (`result`), and then find the unique rows of this matrix. Finally, I count the number of each unique row and return the points that appear in the majority number of arrays as `majorityPts`.